# attach an event to the body when ul is visible, then remove it when invisible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `<ul>` that when clicked, toggles the visibility of another `<ul>`. How can I attach an event to the body of the page when the `<ul>`s are revealed so that the body will hide the `<ul>`.

I am new to writing these sorts things which bubble, and I cannot figure out why what I have done so far seems to work intermittently. When clicked several times, it fails to add the class `open` when the secondary `<ul>` is opened.

And of course, there may be an entirely better way to do this.

```
$(document).on('click', '.dd_deploy', function (e) {
    var ul = $(this).children('ul');
    var height = ul.css('height');
    var width = ul.css('width');
    ul.css('top', "-" + height);
    ul.fadeToggle(50, function () {

        //add open class depending on what's toggled to
        if (ul.hasClass('open')) {
            ul.removeClass('open');
        } else {
            ul.addClass('open');
        }
        //attach click event to the body to hide the ul when
        //body is clickd
        $(document).on('click.ddClick', ('*'), function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
           //if (ul.hasClass('open')) {
                ul.hide();
                ul.removeClass('open')
                $(document).off('click.ddClick');
           // }
        });
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JYVwR/

Comment: Do the work on the click event since that is the event that is showing and hiding the ul.

Comment: @KevinB Hi Kevin, Thanks. Can you be a little bit more specific though? I don't quite see what you mean.

Comment: Can you confirm this is what you want: When you click on dd_deploy, it opens the submenu, and when you click somewhere else, it closes?

Comment: @Aktee I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: @thomas, you explained your problem but you didn't explain your goal. It seems like you're trying to do a kind of navigation menu, and I just wanted to confirm that is what you wanted to do, because there's better ways of doing this..

Comment: @Aktee yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. Can you show me a better way? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest not binding a click event in a click event, even if you are unbinding it. Instead, i would do it this way:

http://jsfiddle.net/JYVwR/2/

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    if ( $(e.target).is(".dd_deploy") ) {
        var ul = $(e.target).children('ul');
        var height = ul.css('height');
        var width = ul.css('width');
        ul.css('top', "-" + height);
        ul.fadeToggle(50, function () {

            //add open class depending on what's toggled to
            if (ul.hasClass('open')) {
                ul.removeClass('open');
            } else {
                ul.addClass('open');
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        $('.dd_deploy').children('ul:visible').fadeOut(50,function(){
            $(this).removeClass("open");
        })
    }
});​
```

If you need to further prevent clicking on the opened menu from closing the menu, add an else if that tests for children of that menu.

Answer (score -1):

You dont' really need all that code. All you need is jquery's [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) class to accomplish what you want. simple code like one below should work.

## Example Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.dd_deploy').click(function(){
        $('ul.dd').toggle();
    });
});​​​​
```

Firstly, you are defining a `document.on` function within a `document.on` function which is fundamentally wrong, you just need to check it once and execute the function once the document is ready.

Secondly why do you want to bind an event to `body.click` ? it's not really a good idea.

## Suggestion

I think you should also look at the [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function which might be useful to you in this case.

## Working Fiddles

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yU4dC/) with click function
[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QSyzC/) with hover function